# Como mapear todas as requisições para um único arquivo?

Tags: apache, htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewrite

Preciso mapear **todas** as requisições que chegam ao servidor da seguinte forma:

```
exemplo.com/joao  =>  exemplo.com/index.pl?u=joao
exemplo.com/joao/ =>  exemplo.com/index.pl?u=joao
```

Meu arquivo `/var/www/.htaccess` está assim até o momento:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+)\/?$ index.pl?u=$1
```

Em casos normais a regra funciona. Porém falha no caso de o diretório `/var/www/joao` existir.

Eu preciso que a URL seja transformada mesmo que o diretório `joao` exista. Alguém tem alguma ideia?

Answer (score -1):

Muito bom.
agora eu tenho um servidor web e outro servidor de aplicativos rodando jboss. minhas requisições passam pelo servidor web. queria fazer a url amigável mas ta dando erro